# Can the Composite Design pattern avoid a Collection (List, HashTable) data structure?

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml, composite

I want a full comprehension of all possible types of the Composite Design Pattern when looking at code. In this code I have a composite object `PeanutButterAndJellySandwich` which contains `Bread`, `PeanutButter` and `Jelly`.

The reason PeanutButterAndJellySandwhich's field variables are all of type food is to account calories

```
interface Food{
    int calories = 9000;
}


class Bread implements Food{
    private String flour;
    private String salt;

}

class Jelly implements Food{
    private String fruit;
    private String sugar;
}

class PeanutButter implements Food{
    private boolean crunchy;
}

class PeanutButterAndJellySandwich implements Food{
    private Food bread;
    private Food jelly;
    private Food peanutButter;

    public void setBread(Bread bread){this.bread=bread;}
    public void setJelly(Jelly jelly){this.jelly=jelly;}
    public void setPeanutButter(PeanutButter butter){this.peanutButter=butter;}
}
```

Is this follow the Composite Design Pattern or does `PeanutButterAndJellySandwhich` need something like `foodItems:ArrayList<Food>`. The UML Diagram would look very similar.

[image: UML Diagram]

I ask this because I have not found this anywhere explicitly stated after about 5 hours of searching and in the application of something like an embedded system we may not want a collection data structure since memory/storage is limited. However, all examples online are utilizing many forms of lists.

Comment: If you really care about memory, you shouldn't choose Java in the first place...

Comment: Haha yes I agree very strongly with that. I was just trying to give an example of why anything like this would ever exist. @renyuneyun

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't read the question carefully. My fault...

Comment: Design patterns are useful shorthand descriptions of code, they're not goals to be achieved. You use a collection when you need some number of other objects, and you don't use it when you don't. "Is it an instance of Composite when the object uses different fields and not a collection?" *might* be a meaningful question, but I'm still not sure I see the usefulness in that framing.

Comment: Hey @chrylis I point this out because I am in college right now and may be tested on this. I also want there to be somewhere in the internet people may refer to this kind of question. At my job I would not stress so much about about following the Composite Design Pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, composite pattern is meant to allow you ignore the difference between components (`Bread`, `Jelly`, `PeanutButterAndJellySandwich`, etc in your case) and their hierarchy, using runtime polymorphism most likely. It's meant to let **you** handle them in a **uniformed** way (through a loop, most likely), and let the **runtime** do the **rest**.

Therefore, since your example just didn't show this intention and manually handled that, I would say this is not a composite pattern, but rather a plain (plan of) use of runtime polymorphism.

However, your code does catch the point where `PeanutButterAndJellySandwich` is a `Food`, enabling the potential future use (e.g. a `PeanutButterAndJellySandwich` with an ingredient `PeanutButterAndJellySandwich`) which is the aim of the composite pattern. (But you didn't show this intention in your code.)

---

p.s.

1. But design patterns are not something sacred. They are meant as a guide rather than a restriction.
2. I would say the question itself doesn't make much sense, because design patterns are not meant to save memory, but to promote good system designs. So they are described in a generic way for easier to describe and understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate it. You have really saved my brain from constantly racing. Also good point I do agree that code maintainability is the point to Object Oriented Programming and Design Patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The composite pattern is used to create tree structures. In case of your sandwich it doesn't make much sense. You have just a simple layer (list) of `Ingredients`. Except you want to have a sandwich as part of a sandwich. To me your design is just broken. Use patterns where they apply. Don't apply patterns bcause they exist.

Comment: Hey @ThomasKilian thanks for pointing this out. You are correct. There was actually more to this original problem because Bread contained Flour and Salt, Jelly contained Sugar and Fruit and Peanut Butter contained Peanuts and Oil. I tried to simplify it so it would not be super long. However, I plan to edit this first thing after my final. Approximately 14 hours from now.

Comment: In most cases a design needs many steps. Don't try to over--simplify since then in the end you just have "things" related to "things". You actually want "semantic things" related.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code and UML diagram and Code.

Comment: Oh, please don't! Make a new question and revert this one since you also accepted an answer as correct. Now that's a mess...

Comment: My apologies. I tried to simplify things since I added more code and I figured that having a method instead of a field variable in the interface makes more sense because all the examples on the internet with Java do that. My mistake in the first place..  I will revert the prompt but before doing so I want to know if you want me to revert everything? Or is anything new here good? I do believe that the new code I have posted comes closer to meeting requirements of the Composite pattern than the last. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Also sorry for the late reply. I have my last two finals tomorrow so I have been studying a lot for them

Comment: Please revert to the state when you accepted. The edit switch allows that. Just copy your current edit and paste it in a new question. You can also refer to your previous question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I will make a new question and revert this one as soon as I finish my finals tomorrow.

Comment: I rolled back your question. You will find your edits under the "edited" switch in the middle below your question so you can use that for the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking the composite pattern as per *Gamma, Helm et. al.* does talk about manipulating children via the interface (in your case, Food), which would tend to lead you to an implementation in which any number of children could be added to (and removed from) any node in the composite tree. A typical implementation might include an abstract super-class that would implement children-management (add, remove etc.) and then concrete sub-types would derive off that. Some thing like this:

[image]

*There are design choices i'm making here but the gist is right.*

More widely, however, *composition* does not necessitate the *composite pattern* be implemented. Using composition is just fine without it, in fact there is a principle also discussed by *Gamma, Helm et. al.* that talks about favouring composition over inheritance and that has nothing to do with the composite pattern per se.

It's tempting to use inheritance as a handy way to reuse code in your program, but that's really not what inheritance is about, which is why composition is favoured as a way to guard against misusing inheritance and creating unmanageable code as a result. I fear this might be the case in your use of the Food interface to get to the Calories member variable. If you are not generalising your design, i.e. you want to be specific about what *PeanutButterAndJellySandwich* contains at design time (in the structure of your code), then what you probably should do is declare the variables inside *PeanutButterAndJellySandwich* using their concrete types. They are *Food*, there's no doubt, but consider what *PeanutButterAndJellySandwich* is going to do with member variables that are all declared as *Food*? Why bother not using an array of Food?

Comment: Hello @muszeo I chose not to use an abstract super class as my example because all the top examples on google have choosen to implement this as an interface

Comment: How do they manage the add/remove methods without repeating code?